# Creating a filterable list with RxJS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I'm trying to get into reactive programming. I use array-functions like map, filter and reduce all the time and love that I can do array manipulation without creating state.

As an exercise, I'm trying to create a filterable list with RxJS without introducing state variables. In the end it should work similar to this:

[image]
[image]

I would know how to accomplish this with naive JavaScript or AngularJS/ReactJS but I'm trying to do this with nothing but RxJS and without creating state variables:

```
var list = [
  'John',
  'Marie',
  'Max',
  'Eduard',
  'Collin'
];

Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('#filter'), 'keyup')
  .map(function(e) { return e.target.value; });

// i need to get the search value in here somehow:
Rx.Observable.from(list).filter(function() {});
```

**Now how do I get the search value into my filter function on the observable that I created from my list?**

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to wrap the `from(list)` as it will need to restart the list observable again every time the filter is changed.  Since that could happen a lot, you'll also probably want to prevent filtering when the filter is too short, or if there is another key stroke within a small time frame.

```
//This is a cold observable we'll go ahead and make this here
var reactiveList = Rx.Observable.from(list);

//This will actually perform our filtering
function filterList(filterValue) {
  return reactiveList.filter(function(e) {
   return /*do filtering with filterValue*/;
  }).toArray();
}


var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('#filter'), 'keyup')
  .map(function(e) { return e.target.value;})

  //The next two operators are primarily to stop us from filtering before 
  //the user is done typing or if the input is too small
  .filter(function(value) { return value.length > 2; })
  .debounce(750 /*ms*/)

  //Cancel inflight operations if a new item comes in.
  //Then flatten everything into one sequence
  .flatMapLatest(filterList);

//Nothing will happen until you've subscribed
source.subscribe(function() {/*Do something with that list*/});
```

This is all adapted from one of the standard examples for RxJS [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/autocomplete/autocomplete.js)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new stream, that takes the list of people and the keyups stream, merge them and scans to filter the latter.

```
const keyup$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(_input, 'keyup')
  .map(ev => ev.target.value)
  .debounce(500);

const people$ = Rx.Observable.of(people)
  .merge(keyup$)
  .scan((list, value) => people.filter(item => item.includes(value)));
```

This way you will have:

-L------------------ people list

------k-----k--k---- keyups stream

-L----k-----k--k---- merged stream

Then you can scan it. As docs says:

> **Rx.Observable.prototype.scan(accumulator, [seed])**
>
> Applies an accumulator function over an observable sequence and returns each
>   intermediate result.

That means you will be able to filter the list, storing the new list on the accumulator.

Once you subscribe, the data will be the new list.

```
people$.subscribe(data =>  console.log(data) ); //this will print your filtered list on console
```

Hope it helps/was clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You can look how I did it here:
https://github.com/erykpiast/autocompleted-select/

It's end to end solution, with grabbing user interactions and rendering filtered list to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [WebRx's List-Projections](http://webrxjs.org/docs/observable-lists.html#topic-list-projections) as well.

[Live-Demo](http://webrxjs.org/examples/observable-list-projection)

**Disclosure**: I am the author of the Framework.